# bootstrap form-group and input-group not getting width

Tags: xslt, bootstrap-4

Is this the correct format for `form-group` and `input-group` I am not getting the correct width  on the txtstartIpAddr input control?

```
        <div class="form-group" id="NewIpRangeRow">
            <label>
              <xsl:text>Start IP Address</xsl:text>
            </label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="txtstartIpAddr" style="width 100 !important;"></input>
            </div>
            <label>
              <xsl:text>End IP Address</xsl:text>
            </label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" id="txtendIpAddr" disabled="true" style="width 100 !important;"></input>
                <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-nccnBlue">
                  <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                    <xsl:text>UpdateAccess(5)</xsl:text>
                  </xsl:attribute>
                  <i class="fa fa-save" style="color:#FFF"></i>
              </span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS syntax is `property-name : property-value` so `width: 100px` not `width 100`.

Comment: Why do I need that when I am using input-group?

Comment: I am telling you that you have as CSS syntax error in your inline `style` attributes, that's all. Don't know what you expect to achieve and why you tag that question as XSLT.